# How to get Firebase ID Token?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to get ID Token to access files on Firebase storage. I'm using C# xamarin.

```
user = await Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
rawResult = await user.User.GetIdToken(false);
if (rawResult is GetTokenResult res)
{
    return res.Token;
}
```

It gives me authentication token that is very long.

But actually I need ID Token that is short.

How do I get ID Token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It gives me authentication token that is very long.But actually I need ID Token that is short.

I use the following code to get current user ID Token, it also very long.

```
 try
        {
            var user = await Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
            var uid = user.User.Uid;              
            var token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);

            return token.Token;
        }
        catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

You said that you want to get short ID Token, I guess that you want to get current **user Uid**

```
  var uid = user.User.Uid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cherry Bu - GetIdTokenAsync(false) is no longer useable (deprecated). Which Nugets and versions are you using please?